# TinyXml2 XMLDocument parse after create new Element crash

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml, tinyxml2, tinyxml++

In TinyXmlv1 i can create a temp Xml Element then Parse document by

```
TiXmlDocument doc;
TiXmlElement * element = new TiXmlElement( "Hello" );
TiXmlText * text = new TiXmlText( "World" );
element->LinkEndChild( text );
doc.Parse("<TAGS></TAGS>"); // It OK
```

Now i want switch to TinyXmlv2 by following:

```
#include "tinyxml2.h"

using namespace tinyxml2;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;
    tinyxml2::XMLElement* newElm = doc.NewElement("Hello");
    newElm->SetText("World");

    doc.Parse("<TAGS></TAGS>"); // This will crash

    return 0;
}
```

I cant understand why it crash.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a "crash" but an `assert` from tinyxml2 because you are "throwing away" `newElem`. You created `newElem` within `XMLDocument` `doc` but `newElem` is just "floating" around as an untracked node until you insert it at a specific location within the `XMLDocument`. Calling `Parse` clears the `XMLDocument` deleting all current nodes and the `assert` is simply a notification that an untracked node is being deleted.

Call one of the `XMLNode::Insert...` methods to add elements to the document in the appropriate place. And, in your case, move the call to `Parse` to create the document element (`<TAGS>`) before creating child elements.

E.g.

```
#include "tinyxml2.h"

using namespace tinyxml2;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    XMLDocument doc;
    doc.Parse("<TAGS></TAGS>");

    XMLElement* newElm = doc.NewElement("Hello");
    newElm->SetText("World");

    doc.InsertEndChild(newElem);

    return 0;
}
```

[My tinyxml2 extension](https://github.com/stanthomas/tinyxml2-ex) offers a convenient helper function (`append_element`) to create and insert an element in a single operation.